# getting error while connecting to jira through unirest

Tags: java, unirest

I tried the below code to connect to jira using unirest api but getting the below exception.

```
HttpResponse<JsonNode> response = Unirest.get("https://apatil.atlassian.net/rest/api/2/applicationrole")
         .basicAuth("email", "api key").header("Accept", "application/json").asJson();
     System.out.println(response.getBody());
```

Getting the below error for above code.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/methods/HttpUriRequest
    at com.mashape.unirest.request.BaseRequest.asJson(BaseRequest.java:68)
    at com.sonata.jira.integeration.JiraIntegeration.getApplicatioRole(JiraIntegeration.java:14)
    at com.sonata.jira.integeration.JiraIntegeration.main(JiraIntegeration.java:21)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: The error message seems very precise: "ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest"

Comment: I have added httpcore and httpclient also still exception only,I hope unirest inbuit having httpclient implementation so no need add it to classpath explicitly.